# screen rotation for sencha app in android device

Tags: android, cordova, sencha-touch-2

Currently I am working for sencha app for android. The App is created and work on android device.
But when I am rotate the device, my application will be closed.
I have no idea to how to solve these problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **AndroidManifest.xml** file put this code in Activity tag

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
```